# JavaScriptでWebsocketの接続がすぐに切れてしまう

Tags: javascript, websocket

JavaScriptでWebsocketのServerに接続したいのですが、接続してもすぐに接続が切れてしまいます。consoleを見ると、ページが読み込まれると、すぐに下記のようにOpenとcloseが表示されてしまいます。なぜ、すぐに切断されるのでしょうか?

console:

```
Open
Close
```

JavaScript

```
var post_button = document.getElementById("post");
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:4283/chat");

function generateDOM(name, content) {
    var base_div = document.createElement("div");
    var p_content = document.createElement("p");
    var p_name = document.createElement("p");
    base_div.className = "message-card";
    p_content.className = "content";
    p_name.className = "name";
    p_name.textContent = name;
    p_content.textContent = content;
    base_div.appendChild(p_name);
    base_div.appendChild(p_content);
    return base_div
}

post_button.onclick = function (e) {
    ws.send(JSON.stringify({Name: name, Message: input_area.value}));
};

ws.onopen = function (e) {
    console.log("Open");
}

ws.onmessage = function (e) {
    var d = JSON.parse(e.data.toString());
    var e = generateCard(d.name, d.message);
    c.appendChild(e);
}

ws.onclose = function () {
    console.log("Close");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`onclose` 関数で [CloseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/CloseEvent) を受け取るようにして、 `code` ([Close Code](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-7.1.5)) や `reason` ([Close Reason](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-7.1.6)) の値を調べれば、何かヒントが得られると思います。

```js
ws.onclose = function (e) {
    console.log("Close Code = " + e.code);
    console.log("Close Reason = " + e.reason);
}
```